# Cant create instance of another class

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add the JPanel created in class viewOne to the JFrame created in class main. However, it is not working.

```
public class main{
  private static JFrame window;

  public static void main(String args[]){
     window = new JFrame();
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     window.setSize(800,800);   
     window.setVisible(true);   

     viewOne(window);
  }
}

public class viewOne {
  private JPanel panel1;

  public viewOne(JFrame frame) {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel1);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    frame.validate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly call `viewOne(window);`. Its the constructor of viewOne you need to call and this is how it is called - `new viewOne(window);`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.